# Possible to define multiple forms in a single .ui file in QtDesigner?

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

I have seen [Use a single source file for many QtDesigner forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065853/use-a-single-source-file-for-many-qtdesigner-forms), which is the gist of my question also, - but it simply recommends:

> My advice is to use it as Qt way. Use seperate classes and seperate files for each form. This approach is better.

However, I would like to specifically know - is it possible *at all* to define multiple forms (say, a "Main Window" and a "Dialog with Buttons Bottom") in a single .ui file, and work with them in QtDesigner?

Basically, for an application of mine, I use QtDesigner .ui file to design the MainWindow, and load that from Python (PyQt5) - and it works great. Now, I'd just like to add a window dialog raised on a click of a button, and I'd also like to use QtDesigner for it, but I wouldn't want to maintain two .ui files. I'd imagine, once such an .ui file (with multiple form definitions) would be loaded in Python, the Python code would just set all forms other than QMainWindow to hidden, and then manage when they are shown appropriately.

(I use QtDesigner on and off, so I do not know it very well - however I recall there was some stuff that QtDesigner couldn't do from the UI, but one could do manually in the .ui file, and after such changes, QtDesigner could still deal with them. So, if there is a way to do this - even if it is not fully supported in the QtDesigner UI - I'd love to know about it, or have a definitive answer that it is not doable).

Comment: The linked question is only talking about source (*.cpp*) and header (*.h*) files, not *.ui* files. So the advice given there is irrelevant to what you're asking. Qt Designer *might have* allowed multiple forms per file - but it didn't. So you have no real options as far as that goes, Of course, just like C++, you can organise your Python modules in whatever way is most appropriate for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

No, you cannot.

### Why not?

UI files are intended for individual widgets (it doesn't matter whether they are intended as top level windows or not) and their possible children.

While I can understand your request, it seems more related to a "project" concept than an UI one. That's not the intent of Designer, which cannot imagine the possible extent of your project; and even if that was the case, it wouldn't be very practical: what if your project could potentially have hundreds of windows? Suppose that you have a main window, open your program, but then you decide to close it: your program would be loading hundreds of windows, but use none of them, causing an unnecessary overhead in the program loading.

The concept is similar to the modularization of OOP: not only you just "load" what you *actually* need, but you also should "split" the project in different files (modules, not unlike python modules) for better maintenance , reusability and overview. What if you want to have two separate "main" UI files for some reason, and, coincidentally, they use a similar dialog? You should copy that dialog every time, and if at some point you forget that step, you might even cause your program to crash as it's trying to access objects that don't exist or have been just slightly renamed.

Furthermore, some interfaces can be really complex, and automatically loading them at startup would be pointless: if you're using the `uic` module, you're requiring unnecessary parsing of the *whole* xml tree of the UI, and that would be for *every time* a new instance for a window from that file is required.

Maybe, someday, developers at Qt will decide to allow "projects" in Designer (which is probably what Qt Creator does, but I've never used it), but `ui` files will still be individual, as they should.

So, don't worry too much, it's more a question of habit and a slightly annoying aspect: if your project is well conceived, and you also properly name your files, it won't be a major problem and it will have its benefits anyway (even if you don't consider them as you could).

<sup>PS: yes, UI files are XML files and *can* be edited; you could even create/edit an UI file and do things Designer couldn't. But that's just an "unexpected feature" (or *smart hack*), for which you can *never* be always sure about the outcome. In future (or just *different*) versions the parser could be[come] more strict, with the result that your UI becomes completely unusable. That's not unlike editing pyuic files: the programs that use them expect a *known* behavior (the XML output of Designer), and common, accepted usage. As the recent pyuic file headers (which, I'd like to mark, was added after a personal suggestion of mine) report: "Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing" ;-)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - that is what I needed, an explicit answer; so I don't keep asking myself the same question. Also, great explanation!